# Android studio is not opening

Tags: android, android-studio

I have no idea what is the issue with it, today I've used it and it was working just fine, now I am trying to open it but it simply cannot open. There are no errors or such. I've searched everything everywhere no solution so far. The only thing I found was to add enviromental variable and so I did. But the same thing again. Reinstalled it, reinstalled java jdk. No result. Anyone with ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Try "C:\Users\userX.AndroidStudio2.3"
open "studio64.exe.vmoptions" with notepad and delete vm options (make this file empty)

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question was raised long back but posting the answer to help someone stuck in the recent days,
as I was able to resolve the same issue by refer to the solution provided in Android Developer Portal,

[Studio doesn't start after upgrade](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#studio-config-directories)

If Studio doesn't start after an upgrade, the problem may be due to an invalid Android Studio configuration imported from a previous version of Android Studio or an incompatible plugin. As a workaround, try deleting (or renaming, for backup purposes) the directory below, depending on the Android Studio version and operating system, and start Android Studio again. This will reset Android Studio to its default state, with all third-party plugins removed.

For Android Studio 4.1 and later:

Windows: %APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio Example: C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

macOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio Example: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Linux: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio Example: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1 and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

For Android Studio 4.0 and earlier:

Windows: %HOMEPATH%.AndroidStudio\config
Example: C:\Users\your_user_name.AndroidStudio3.6\config

macOS: ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio
Example: ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio3.6

Linux: ~/.AndroidStudio/config
Example: ~/.AndroidStudio3.6/config